# Why am I getting the error Employee Controller required a bean of Employee Repository that could not be found?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am working on Spring Boot, Maven and MySQL.

I am getting this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field employeeRepository in com.example.demo.controller.EmployeeController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository' in your configuration.
```

I have tried all kinds of solutions found online such as putting @Repository annotations , maintaining the order of the classes , doing a maven clean and running , updating maven project , using a constructor to autowire etc. , but still this error has not been resolved. I also have my pom.xml updated and the screenshots of the important files are as follows -

[Project Structure] - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQu6M.png)

## **Employee Controller -**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.controller.*;
import com.example.demo.model.*;
import com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import com.example.demo.Exception.ResourceNotFoundException;




@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class EmployeeController{
    
    
    @Autowired
     private  EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
//      @Autowired
//      
//      public EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
//          this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
//      }
        
    @GetMapping("/employees")
       public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
                return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId)
        throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
          .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + employeeId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(employee);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
    
    
    @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId,
         @Valid @RequestBody Employee employeeDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + employeeId));

        employee.setEmailId(employeeDetails.getEmailId());
        employee.setLastName(employeeDetails.getLastName());
        employee.setFirstName(employeeDetails.getFirstName());
        employee.setDeptName(employeeDetails.getDeptName());
        final Employee updatedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedEmployee);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId)
         throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
       .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + employeeId));

        employeeRepository.delete(employee);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }
}
```

## **Employee.java ( The Model File ) -**

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;


@Entity

@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "First_Name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "Last_Name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "Email_Address")
    private String emailId;
    
    @Column(name = "Dept_Name")
    private String deptName;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String email) {
        this.emailId = email;
    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    public Employee( String firstName, String lastName, String emailId, String deptName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }
    
    public Employee() {
    }
}
```

## **Employee Repository**

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.beans.JavaBean;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.Employee;


//@Service
//@Component



@Service @Repository @Component
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{

}
```

## **DemoApplication.java ( The Main File )**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

## **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CURD_Application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CURD_Application</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>

        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

        <!--       Added ones -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final </version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

    

        <!--        Added ones ended-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.23</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions> <!-- important detail -->
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

    </build>


</project>
```

## Employees Table

Employees Table - ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVPJh.png )
So please tell me how to fix this error.

I tried adding the annotations , rebuilding the projects , using constructor etc. still it is showing this error , and if I remove the autowired annotation it shows me this  -

{"timestamp":"2023-07-27T14:40:24.596+00:00","message":"Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository.findAll()" because "this.employeeRepository" is null","details":"uri=/api/v1/employees"}

And Going on , I want to link it to angular project but it shows this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVzml.png)

and this in localhost:8080 -

{timestamp: "2023-07-27T13:59:25.065+00:00",…}
details
:
"uri=/api/v1/employees"
message
:
"Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository.findAll()" because "this.employeeRepository" is null"
timestamp
:
"2023-07-27T13:59:25.065+00:00"

Comment: Because your dependencies are a mess. Remove all non `org.springframework.boot` dependencies, except your JDBC driver. Fix the `javax.persistence` to `jakarta.persistence` import in your entities and restart your application.

Comment: Still it is not working :(

Comment: Then I doubt you did as I suggested, also those annotations on your repository are useless, so remove them.

Comment: I did , but still it didn't workout so I created a new project by applying the service packages and interface and it worked finally :))